# How to select N max values in a mongodb database in PyMongo

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to select a number of the biggest elements in a mongodb collection. For example, my database collection is structured as:

| username | score |
| --- | --- |
| person_a | 500 |
| person_b | 600 |

I already know how to select the person with the max score value (written below):

> max = leaderboard_data.find_one(sort=[("score", -1)])["score"]

But how would I edit this to select *n* biggest items in the mongodb database collection based off of the "score" field? Like the top 10 scores for example?

I've seen the solution using the $limit notation when I was looking at the mongodb specific docs but I have no idea how to use it in PyMongo.

Comment: If you want more than one document then you should use `find` rather than `find_one`. And the latter doesn't accept a `limit` since it's definitionally already limited (to one). The former should though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `find()` statement in combination with `sort` and `limit`.

```
import pymongo

db = pymongo.MongoClient()['test']

# Set up some data
for i in range(20):
    db['mycollection'].insert_one({'username': f'person{i}', 'score': i})

# sort by score descending, limit to top 10
for record in db['mycollection'].find({}, {'_id': 0}).sort('score', pymongo.DESCENDING).limit(10):
    print(record)
```

prints:

```
{'username': 'person19', 'score': 19}
{'username': 'person18', 'score': 18}
{'username': 'person17', 'score': 17}
{'username': 'person16', 'score': 16}
{'username': 'person15', 'score': 15}
{'username': 'person14', 'score': 14}
{'username': 'person13', 'score': 13}
{'username': 'person12', 'score': 12}
{'username': 'person11', 'score': 11}
{'username': 'person10', 'score': 10}
```